# How to get json from queryset?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This class has query for database:

```
class arizakestirimi_func(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = arizakestirimiserializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = isyeriarizabilgileri.objects.raw("""
            SELECT
            M.id as id,M.isyeri as isyeri,
            DATE_PART('day',(M.tarih)::timestamp - (D.mindate)::timestamp) * 24 +
            DATE_PART('hour',(M.tarih)::timestamp - (D.mindate)::timestamp) +
            DATE_PART('minute',(M.tarih)::timestamp - (D.mindate)::timestamp) / 60 as zamanfarki
            FROM arizakestirimi_isyeriarizabilgileri M
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT ON (isyeri) isyeri,id as id,durustahmini,tarih as mindate
         FROM arizakestirimi_isyeriarizabilgileri 
         WHERE durustahmini='MEKANIK ARIZA' AND isyeri='15400001'
         ORDER BY isyeri, tarih ASC) D
            ON M.isyeri = D.isyeri AND M.durustahmini = D.durustahmini
            ORDER BY M.tarih ASC

          """)
        return queryset
```

This is the serializer class, I have defined it in serializer.py:

```
class arizakestirimiserializer(serializers.Serializer):

    isyeri = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    zamanfarki= serializers.FloatField()
```

When ı use django rest framework ı got this json:

```
[
    {
        "isyeri": "15400001",
        "zamanfarki": 0.0
    },
    {
        "isyeri": "15400001",
        "zamanfarki": 7.0
    },
    {
        "isyeri": "15400001",
        "zamanfarki": 603.0
    },
    {
        "isyeri": "15400001",
        "zamanfarki": 607.0
    },
    {
        "isyeri": "15400001",
        "zamanfarki": 1655.0
    },
    {
        "isyeri": "15400001",
        "zamanfarki": 1661.0
    }
]
```

I want to use this json directly inside "get_queryset" method. How can convert queryset result to json with given field name like "serializers.py".
Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you need JSON inside the get_queryset method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the JSON inside the get_queryset method, you can edit your code as such:

```
class arizakestirimi_func(ListAPIView):

serializer_class = arizakestirimiserializer

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = isyeriarizabilgileri.objects.raw("""
        YOUR QUERY
      """)

    data = self.serializer_class(queryset, many=True).data # This will give you the JSON data

    return queryset
```

Comment: Firstly Thanks @Mehak. But I received this error."Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `isyeri` on serializer `arizakestirimiserializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `RawQuerySet` instance.Original exception text was: 'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'isyeri'."

Comment: I checked in a similar code of mine, adding `many=True` seems to work. I've updated the answer. Please give it a try.